# TypeError when attempting to render static HTML page

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to render a static HTML page when a GET request is made to the root directory (`/`).

However, I receive the following error when accessing the root directory (`http://localhost:3000/`):

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_locals' of undefined
```

**Project Structure**

```
index.js
node_modules
public
|-- html
|   |--index.html
```

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = 3000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(port);
console.log('Server running on port ' + port + '.');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    app.render(__dirname + '/html/index.html');
})
```

I can access my static HTML page by going to `http://localhost:3000/html/index.html`. However, calls to `app.render()` fail. I suspect it has something to do with the directory I am passing into `app.render()`.

Comment: Use `res.sendFile` instead of `app.render`. I think `express` is to render `html` files directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You shouldn't use `app.render`, it should be `res.render`
2. `res.render` is supposed to render content with template engine, for example, mustache, ejs, jade, etc. You shouldn't use it to render pure html files.
3. if you want to send *.html content, try to use `res.sendFile`

---

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/html/index.html');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    app.render(__dirname + '/html/index.html');
});
```

Try using it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render(__dirname + '/html/index.html');
})
```

**res** rather than app in the function